# Excel function that will search column, pick out arrays, and sum their respective totals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a function to search my spreadsheet for which there will be multiple arrays. I need the search to include all the cells in between two specific headers throughout the spreadsheet but only sum certain cells between these headers from respective data.

```
{'A':['dog','cat','dog','dog'],
 'B':[4,2,1,2],
 'C':['dog'],
 'D':[3],
}
```

Per this example, I need the function to search the 1st column for any cells located in between header "A" and "B". Then I need the function to pick out the cells named "dog" and sum the totals (7).

Answer (score 1):

`SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2,
         criteria2], …)`
 can let you do this if you specify what ranges to sum and what ranges contain the criteria and what that criteria is.

If you have the following,

```
 A  B    C  D
Dog 4   dog 3
cat 2       
dog 1       
dog 2
```

`=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"dog")`